# Spark HBase Connection Timeout / Hang

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to test reads and writes to hbase on my local machine.

I'm using the cloudera quick start docker image to host hbase / hadoop / zookeeper etc.

I have the following code:

```
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Database Benchmark")

        val sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
        val tableName = "testTable"
        val HBaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
        // Add local HBase conf
        HBaseConf.set("hbase.master", "localhost")
        HBaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","localhost")
        HBaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
        HBaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)

        val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(HBaseConf)
        val table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName))

        val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 100)
          .map(i => (i.toString, i+1))

        try {
            read(table)

            write(rdd)
        } catch {
            case e : Exception =>  println("uh oh") // uh oh.
        } finally {
            table.close
            connection.close
        }


    }

    def write(toWrite :  RDD[(String, Int)]): Put = {
        val putter = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("Row2"))
        putter.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("test"),
            Bytes.toBytes("column1"), Bytes.toBytes(toWrite.toString()))
    }

    def read(table : Table) = {
        val row = table.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes("newRow")))
        println(row.toString)
    }
```

Currently my code doesn't really do much, I'm just trying to get a read and write to work, but when I attempt to connect to the container I get the following hang-up message indefinitely:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/10/25 14:56:00 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.0.1
16/10/25 14:56:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/10/25 14:56:01 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: {user}
16/10/25 14:56:01 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: {user}
16/10/25 14:56:01 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/10/25 14:56:01 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/10/25 14:56:01 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set({user}); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set({user}); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 57682.
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/b5/6bhlwry949n3mpwppt4m5_1jcmsf2g/T/blockmgr-d4aaf6d1-ca0d-4c9b-9e08-9b7716e89791
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2004.6 MB
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 127.0.0.1, and started at http://127.0.0.1:4040
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 57683.
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 127.0.0.1:57683
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 127.0.0.1, 57683)
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 127.0.0.1:57683 with 2004.6 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 127.0.0.1, 57683)
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 127.0.0.1, 57683)
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x5bd73d1a connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=localhost:2181
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=10.171.46.220
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_101
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/Users/{user}/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/b5/6bhlwry949n3mpwppt4m5_1jcmsf2g/T/
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Mac OS X
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=x86_64
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=10.11.6
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name={user}
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/Users/{user}
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/Users/{user}/code/scala/HBaseTest
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x5bd73d1a0x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
16/10/25 14:56:02 INFO ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x157fc012352000e, negotiated timeout = 40000
16/10/25 14:56:41 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=38307 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'testTable,newRow,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=quickstart.cloudera,60020,1477401812367, seqNum=0
16/10/25 14:56:51 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=48337 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'testTable,newRow,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=quickstart.cloudera,60020,1477401812367, seqNum=0
...
16/10/25 15:00:56 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=48468 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'testTable,newRow,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=quickstart.cloudera,60020,1477401812367, seqNum=0
16/10/25 15:01:08 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/10/25 15:01:08 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://127.0.0.1:4040
16/10/25 15:01:08 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/10/25 15:01:08 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/10/25 15:01:08 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/10/25 15:01:08 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/10/25 15:01:08 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/10/25 15:01:08 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/10/25 15:01:08 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/10/25 15:01:08 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/b5/6bhlwry949n3mpwppt4m5_1jcmsf2g/T/spark-cc1a87f4-ae09-489e-8957-c2c8a3788e9b


Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

I don't believe it's the docker container's ports because I forward the required ports with the following:

```
docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -p 8888:8888 -p 7180:7180 -p 8000:80 -p 50070:50070 -p 8020:8020 -p 7077 -p 60000:60000 -p 60020:60020 -p 2181:2181  cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

The hbase-site.xml is as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rest.port</name>
    <value>8070</value>
    <description>The port for the HBase REST server.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/hbase</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.ipc.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.ipc.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.thrift.info.bindAddress</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Any idea what the issue could possibly be?

Comment: can you post the full logs from yarn applicationId

Comment: @NirmalRam is there a difference between yarn logs and the cmdline I'm running the app in?

Comment: it may point you to the root cause

Comment: @NirmalRam there aren't any applications to trace the logs for on my hadoop server, and the only other logs available are the application output that is in the command line. I've updated the question to have a full copy of those.

Comment: can you share the hbase-site.xml @A. Gorton

Comment: @NirmalRam updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

I didn't have my container's hostname in my /etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1    quickstart.cloudera
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Change

```
 HBaseConf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000")
```

2) In hbase-site.xml,add

```
    <property>
      <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
      <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
    </property>
<property>
```

3) Are you having hbase-client https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client in your build.sbt file?

Comment: Tried 1, no change. Number 2 causes the hbase:meta... to be replaced by 'at null'. Number 3 was already included in the build.